# KTBoost.BoostingRegressor TypeError: __cinit__() takes exactly 5 positional arguments (6 given)

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, init

I'm trying to run a BoostingRegressor model from the KTBoost package for binary classification, and i'm facing this error. I do not understand what it may cause it, nor any course of action I should follow to fix it.
Is there something I can do to give more information? plshelpme

```
Xtrain = df.iloc[:, 2:492]
ytrain = df.Target
model = KTBoost.BoostingRegressor(loss='tobit', yl=0, yu=100)
model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out. This is now fixed as of version 0.1.14 of KTBoost. It was a wrong dependency on scikit-learn. Note that you need the newest version of scikit-learn (scikit-learn>=0.21.3).

In the future, please open an issue on https://github.com/fabsig/KTBoost. It will be answered faster there.